# Can I make the UI text on iPhone/iOS smaller?

Tags: email, iphone, text, ios

I have pretty good eyes, and I'd like to be able to see more than 5 emails at a time in the list view. I realize I can reduce the number of preview lines, but I want to keep the preview and just make everything smaller. Seriously, the from labels are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no. As of iOS 5, there's no method for the user to adjust font/interface sizes unless the app gives you a specific control for it. iOS Mail does have a setting for minimum font size, but it only applies to the body of the message, not the message lists.